# JavaScript spread operator with class instances

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I modify a class instance using the spread operator, while keeping its constructor the same?

The question may be clearer with an example.

```js
class User {
    constructor({ name = "", age = 0 }) {
        this.name = name
        this.age = age
    }

    getName() {
        return this.name
    }

    getAge() {
        return this.age
    }
}
```

Creating a regular instance works fine:

```js
const u1 = new User({ name: 'John Doe', age: 33 })
console.log(u1.getAge()) // 33
```

What does not work is using the spread operator with the instance:

```js
const u2 = { ...u1, age: 34 }
console.log(u2.getAge()) //
```

I read that the spread operator only copies *own enumerable properties*, so I also tried this:

```js
const u3 = { ...u1, ...User.prototype, age: 34 }
console.log(u3.getAge())
```

This works better (it allows me to call the methods in `User`), but still breaks when using `instanceof` or `Object.isPrototypeOf()`:

```js
console.log(u1 instanceof User) // true
console.log(u2 instanceof User) // false
console.log(u3 instanceof User) // false

console.log(User.isPrototypeOf(u1)) // true
console.log(User.isPrototypeOf(u2)) // false
console.log(User.isPrototypeOf(u3)) // false
```

I also tried these, but they didn't work either:

```js
const u4 = Object.assign({ age: 34 }, u1)
const u5 = Object.assign({ age: 34 }, u1, User.prototype)
```

So, TL:DR, is it possible to create a copy of a class instance which changes some properties of the parent, but keeps a reference to its constructor?

Hope I made myself clear. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Because you're creating a new plain old javascript object. Aren't the braces `{` and `}` a clue?

Comment: Hi, why don't you just create setter function for to change values? As far as i understand cause you are creating a new object it's not gonna be an instance of your `User` class.

Comment: The closest to what you want using the spread syntax is: `const u6 = new User({ ...u1, age: 34 });`

Comment: In general, I wouldn’t recommend doing this as a caller. The type should know how to copy itself, i.e. implement either `.clone()` or `.withAge()` methods, implemented like `withAge(newAge) { return new User({name: this.name, age: newAge}); }`, for `const u2 = u1.withAge(34)`.

Comment: thanks, that's helpful. Any better way to do this, though?

Comment: Did you try `u2 = {...u1, age: 34}; Object.setPrototypeOf(u2, Object.getPrototypeOf(u1))`?

Comment: Would like to keep it in one statement if possible (based on the other answers, it is!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the `{ }` object literal notation you *always* create a plain object, never an instance of your custom class. You should use the `new` operator to get a new instance (or `Object.create`):

```js
class User {
    constructor({ name = "", age = 0 }) {
        this.name = name
        this.age = age
    }

    getName() {
        return this.name
    }

    getAge() {
        return this.age
    }
}

const u1 = new User({ name: 'John Doe', age: 33 })
console.log(u1.getName(), u1.getAge()) // John Doe, 33

const u2 = new User({ ...u1, age: 34 });
console.log(u2.getName(), u2.getAge()) // John Doe, 34
```

Comment: Good if constructor accepts enumerable properties of its own instance, but if it does not, you'd need to construct the new instance with valid options, rather than a spread version of its own instance.