# Typescript Intersections Example

Tags: typescript

I was taking a typescript course and one of the examples for intersections was having a function that returned the intersection of the Date type and an object that has a date property called end. The code below is the example.
and the [See typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA8gOQKIH0DqSkGkYF4YCMADCTAFQwBsR5VNFATACy0DsMA9B4QO4wCWYGAFsIAKC7cAtDOABXKDKliAZnLDAo-cCICGAawCmaQ4f0AKAJQAuGABFdUQzABkMAN4xDYACa2HTjAAvh5iMJwcgKDUMABOhlByMUJQAJ4ADoZiYTCgkLDQujGw+GCGfAGGVtm50F6+eDCl5Y6VBUUAdABuugA2coZwKlYwANTwyOiYWJZZ4XEJSR4w7SttUAA0dT7BETD6gtsgKvAARgBWhprtuhAQ-ADmYGJBWTWwUAAW-BAmZg3CBmMpgsM0+31++naUBAAEkAMpwOFQGKCe5VLjhGAAPQA-GIwT9ge1vD4obCEUiUWA0TMMZj6bigA) can be run in the typescript playground. The issue is that on the line were thisWeek.toISOString() is called it causes an error. I'm just trying to understand why it wouldn't work since it is supposed to be a return type of Date with an extra field of end. Is this just a bad example or what?

```
const ONE_WEEK = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1w in ms
function makeWeek(): Date & { end: Date } {
  const start = new Date()
  const end = new Date(start.valueOf() + ONE_WEEK)

  return { ...start, end } // kind of Object.assign
}

const thisWeek = makeWeek()
thisWeek.toISOString()
// line above causes error
thisWeek.end.toISOString()
```

Comment: Spreading `new Date` gives `{}`

Comment: This is a missing feature of TS,see [ms/TS#9726](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9726).  TS has very little idea if a property is enumerable/own.  If you want to do this you should write `return Object.assign(start, {end})` instead.  But TS didn't catch the bug because of that missing feature.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Please change question title to point at the specific problem (type is impoper after object spread)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript spread operator with class instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62488227/javascript-spread-operator-with-class-instances)